# Selecting StoryBoard in AppDelegate based on logged in or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, appdelegate

I am trying to Display Selected ViewController based on user has Logged in inside the app or not.if user has logged in then it should display `HomeViewController`, if not then it should display `InitialViewController`.My Initial StoryBoard is `MainStoryBoard` and LoginVC are in `InitialStoryBoard`. Below is my sample code and struggling lot to fix this issue.can anybody help to fix this issue .

> */*- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions*
>   /
>
> ```
> BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
> NSLog(isLoggedIn ? @"Yes" : @"No");
> NSLog([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] ? @"Yes" : @"No"); 
> if (!isLoggedIn) {
>     NSString *device2;
>     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
>     {
>         device2 = @"InitialStoryboard_iPad";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         device2 = @"InitialStoryboard_iPhone";
>     }
>     NSLog(@"device :%@",device2);
>     UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:device2 bundle:nil];
>     InitialVC *initialController = [storyboard2 instantiateInitialViewController];
>    //        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:initialController animated:YES completion:nil];
>    //        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:initialController animated:NO];
>     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
>     self.window.rootViewController = initialController;
>     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
> }
> ```

If Login is Successful then i am not able to `dismissCurrentVC` as Initial is `RootVC`.If login is Successful then it should make DismissVC if `MainStoryBoard` is Initial Storyboard.or login Successful should make `HomeVC` PresentVCModally if `InitialStoryBoard` is InitialStoryboard.Hope you can understand my Issue.

*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: So where is your issue? On initial launch of the app, or when user logs in you want to dismiss rootViewController and reorder viewController stack??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using different storyboards, I suggest you use only one storyboard (for each device) which contains the RootVC and LoginVC. (RootVC is default initial VC)

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userName"].length){
    NSLog(@"User Logged In, Show Root VC");
    //RootVC is Default.
}else{
    NSLog(@"User Not Logged In, Show Login NVC");
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNVC"];
}
```

After user logged in, you can then switch back to rootVC:

```
- (void)loginAndShowRootVC{
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootVCID"];
}
```